# Not able to parse generic Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am working with generic codable to pass network response. I have created below function which decode data and return in result:

Here is piece of that function:

```
 guard let jsonDataUnwrapped = jsonData,
                  let result: ServerResponse<T> = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse<T>.self, from: jsonDataUnwrapped) else {
                completionHandler(.error(APIError.init(type: .parsingError)))
                return
            }
```

Code in ServerResponse:

```
struct ServerResponse<T: Codable> : Codable {
    var response: T
    var errors: [ServerError]
}

struct ServerError : Codable {
    var code: Int
    var message: String
}
```

In codable class i am doing this:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
        firstName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        phoneNumber = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .phoneNumber)
        if let status = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .accountStatus) {
            accountStatus = UserStatus(rawValue: status)!
        }
    }
```

This code work proper when i get data in response key. But there is a case where i will also get empty response key and have some errors:

```
{
    "response": {},
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "104",
            "message": "Authentication failed"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i get empty response i need errors array but i am not able to get that.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very helpful if you added also the error message you get, but looking at the code it's obvious

> Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.

In JSON **everything** in double quotes is `String` even `"104"` or `"false"`

```
struct ServerError : Codable {
    let code: String
    let message: String
}
```

It's not related to the issue but declare the struct members as constant (`let`) as you are not going to mutate them.

Comment: please check updated question. It is returning from guard let. Although i have made changes that you have mentioned in answer still not working.

Comment: **What** is not working? Don't ignore errors with `try?`, catch the error.

Comment: When response is empty i am not getting errors from `JSONDecoder().decode`.

Comment: Please add a concrete example, your example will throw a `Use of undeclared type 'T'` compiler error.